# Show/Hide different forms based on a option selected

Tags: javascript, forms, show-hide

I would like to know how to show/hide different forms based one form's selection.

In the sample code below all three forms are automatically set to display:none. I would like to only show one of the "hidden" forms if its corresponding value is selected from the "shower" form. So if option "Form 1" is selected from the "shower" form, then show Form 1 below; if option "Form 2" is selected from the "shower" form, then show Form 2; and so on.

Preferably with a fade in/out animation to it or another light animation.

Here is a sample...

```
<form id="form-shower">
<select>
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="form_name1">Form 1</option>
<option value="form_name2">Form 2</option>
<option value="form_name3">Form 3</option>
</select>
</form>

<form name="form_name1" id="form_1" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form name="form_name2" id="form_2" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>

<form name="form_name3" id="form_3" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 3---->
</form>
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use jQuery to help you with it :

```
<form id="form-shower">
<select id="myselect">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="form_name1">Form 1</option>
<option value="form_name2">Form 2</option>
<option value="form_name3">Form 3</option>
</select>
</form>

<form name="form_name1" id="form_name1" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form name="form_name2" id="form_name2" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>

<form name="form_name3" id="form_name3" style="display:none">
<!---- THIS IS FORM 3---->
</form>
<script>
$("#myselect").on("change", function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
})
</script>
```

I added an id to your select and change the id name of your three forms :)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have one problem with this code, the first time that some option is selected it does nothing, but when I select another one, then it shows .

Answer (score 1):

just add this to the end of the HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').change(function(e){
            $this = $(e.target);
            var selected_form = $this.text().replace(' ','_name');
            $('form').hide(2000, 'easeOutExpo');
            $(selected_form).show(2000, 'easeOutExpo');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="form_1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="form_2">Form 2</option>
    <option value="form_3">Form 3</option>
</select>

<form name="form_1" id="form_1" style="display:none">
<input type="text" value="1">
</form>

<form name="form_2" id="form_2" style="display:none">
<input type="text" value="2">
</form>

<form name="form_3" id="form_3" style="display:none">
<input type="text" value="3">
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JS:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
});​
```

Sample at
http://jsfiddle.net/dfYAs/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can add this to the top of your HTML:

```
<script>
function changeForm(form) {
  for (var i=0; i<form.length; i++){
    var form_op = form.options[i].value;
    if (form_op == form.value) {
      document.getElementsByName(form_op)[0].style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementsByName(form_op)[0].style.display = "none";
    }
   }
  }
</script>
```

and then add `onChange="changeForm(this)"` to your main form.
// onChange not case sensitive.

Comment: Hi RocketDonkey, this solution works, but as I choose different selections the forms do not disappear they just add on to the page as I select more...

Comment: Ha, I guess that would be useful huh? Looks like you got the answer, but I'll adjust mine in case you need a jQuery-less response.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, this setup will show/hide those forms dynamically with no external libraries:

```
function changeOptions(selectEl) {
  let selectedValue = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value;
  let subForms = document.getElementsByClassName('className')
  for (let i = 0; i < subForms.length; i += 1) {
    if (selectedValue === subForms[i].name) {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block')
    } else {
      subForms[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none') 
    }
  }
}
```

Then the html:

```
<select onchange="changeOptions(this)">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="form_1">Form 1</option>
  <option value="form_2">Form 2</option>
  <option value="form_3">Form 3</option>
</select>

<form class="className" name="form_1" id="form_1" style="display:none">
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 1---->
</form>

<form class="className" name="form_2" id="form_2" style="display:none">
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 2---->
</form>

<form class="className" name="form_3" id="form_3" style="display:none">
  <!---- THIS IS FORM 3---->
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

make this

1. create function javascript that help u with that work, something like this

```js
    function FFF(){
        var opc = document.getElementById("form-shower").value;
        switch(opc)
        {
            'form_name1':
                document.getElementById('form_1').style.display = "block"; // or inline or none whatever
                break;

        }
    }
```

2. Create event

```html
<select id='id_selec' onChange='javascript:FFF();'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.green {
  background: #228B22;
}

.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option>Choose Color</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="check" class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div id="check" class=" box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div id="check" class="box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
      var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
      if (optionValue) {
        $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
        $("." + optionValue).show();
      } else {
        $(".box").hide();
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.green {
  background: #228B22;
}

.blue {
  background: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option>Choose Color</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="check" class="red box">You have selected <strong>red option</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div id="check" class="green box">You have selected <strong>green option</strong> so i am here</div>
  <div id="check" class="blue box">You have selected <strong>blue option</strong> so i am here</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just being a critic here: you should include at least some text that explains what the code above does.